# Как добавить в объект новый метод и значение

Tags: javascript, json, объекты

Имеется [объект](https://jsfiddle.net/o33teyyw/) в котором есть данные, при добавлении новых методов и значений, мне выдает ошибку, что скрипту не удается считать новый параметр.

**Добавление с условием того, что название нового метода и значения передается мне переменной.**

Фото ошибки:
[image: ошибка чтения массива]

Код:

```
var foo = {

    "gd": {
            "name": "raeeeennn",
            "list": {
                    "ivan":{
                         "name":"nameeeeeeee",
                         "date1":"27.08.1856",
                         "date2":"28.05.1916",
                         "live":"xxx",
                         "description":{
                                "default":"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                                "other":"bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
};

document.write(foo.gd.list.ivan.description.default+'<br>');

var name = 'aaa';
var raen = 'gd';
foo[gd].list[name].description.default = 'aaaaaaaaaaa';


document.write(foo.gd.list.ivan.description.default+'<br>');
```

Comment: ошибка в предпоследней строке, правильно `foo['gd'].list['ivan'].description.default` - не `name`, а `ivan`.

Comment: `var name = 'ivan';` `foo[raen].li...`

Comment: @Jean-Claude, я не хочу заменять те параметры, в "ivan", которые у меня есть, я хочу рядом возле "ivan" положить еще один объект с именем которое будет передаваться переменной "name", что бы в "list" были и "ivan" и "то что переменной передал", сейчас передается "aaa"

Comment: @igor, я выше отписал, что хочу не заменить в "ivan", а добавить новый

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас нельзя добавить `default`, пока не создана структура выше - description, и имя нового человека, делаю так, копирую структуру первого человека (Ивана) новому Антону, а затем внутрь Антона новое дефолтное значение `default`.

Замечание - доступ к элементам объекта черех квадратные скобки - только через кавычки - `foo.gd.list['ivan']` или переменную `name = 'ivan'; foo.gd.list[name]`.

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/o33teyyw/1/).

```js
var foo = {

  "gd": {
    "name": "raeeeennn",
    "list": {
      "ivan": {
        "name": "nameeeeeeee",
        "date1": "27.08.1856",
        "date2": "28.05.1916",
        "live": "xxx",
        "description": {
          "default": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
          "other": "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

document.write(foo.gd.list.ivan.description.default+'<br>');

var name = 'anton';

foo.gd.list[name] = foo.gd.list.ivan;
foo.gd.list[name].description.default = "newText";

document.write(foo.gd.list[name].description.default);
```

Получится в итоге вот что:

```
var foo = {

    "gd": {
        "name": "raeeeennn",
        "list": {
            "ivan": {
                "name": "nameeeeeeee",
                "date1": "27.08.1856",
                "date2": "28.05.1916",
                "live": "xxx",
                "description": {
                    "default": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                    "other": "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
                },
            "anton": {
                "name": "nameeeeeeee",
                "date1": "27.08.1856",
                "date2": "28.05.1916",
                "live": "xxx",
                "description": {
                    "default": "newText",
                    "other": "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
                }
                }
            }

        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, проблему решил